# Cuando hago display que scrollie para que se vea el elemento (sin jquery)

Tags: javascript, html

Basicamente necesitaria que me ayudaran para que cuando aprieto el boton de la pregunta y se abre la respuesta tambien scrollie para que pueda ver en la pantalla la respuesta. Ya que lo que pasa que cuando abro la tercer pregunta no puedo ver la respuesta y tengo que bajar yo scrolliando. Gracias

```
<ul class="preguntas-help">
  <li><h2 onclick='showHide(0)'>¿Quienes somos?</h2></li>
  <li><p style= "display: none"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
   </p></li>
  <li><h2 onclick='showHide(1)'>¿Cómo funciona?</h2></li>
  <li><p style= "display: none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
   </p></li>
  <li><h2 onclick='showHide(2)'>¿Qué son los grados?</h2></li>
  <li><p  style= "display: none"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
  </p></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
function showHide(num) {
var parrafo = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
parrafo[num].style.display == "none" ? parrafo[num].style.display = 'block' : parrafo[num].style.display ='none';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Aquí tienes otra solución (la habría puesto, pero vi que ya te respondieron). [Ver demo](http://jsbin.com/cagokixari/edit?html,css,js,output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, sin modificar mucho tu codigo actual puedes usar `location.hash` con el ID del elemento que quieres quede al tope en el scroll. Esto fuerza el navegador a scrollear (si es posible).

Este ejemplo, scrollea a los parrafos directamente.

```js
function showHide(num) {
  var parrafo = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
  parrafo[num].style.display == "none" ? parrafo[num].style.display = 'block' : parrafo[num].style.display ='none';

  // cambias el HASH y el navegador hace todo el trabajo
  location.hash = parrafo[num].id
}
```

```html
<ul class="preguntas-help">
  <li><h2 onclick='showHide(0)'>¿Quienes somos?</h2></li>
  <li><p id="p1" style= "display: none"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
   </p></li>
  <li><h2 onclick='showHide(1)'>¿Cómo funciona?</h2></li>
  <li><p id="p2" style= "display: none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
   </p></li>
  <li><h2 onclick='showHide(2)'>¿Qué son los grados?</h2></li>
  <li><p id="p3" style= "display: none"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  </p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: te RE contra agradezco! esta fue la solución! Anduvo 10 puntos! mil gracias!!